# Open-gl program not taking user input in code-blocks

Tags: c, opengl, glut

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>



void swap(int a,int b){
    int e = a;
    a=b;
    b=e;
}

void myInit(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.9,0.9,0.8,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glPointSize(2.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,1000.0,0.0,600.0);
}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
    //int x1=0,y1=0,x2=500,y2=500;
    if(x2<x1){
       int e = x1;
       x1=x2;x2=e;
       e = y1;
       y1=y2;y2=e;
    }
    //bresenhams algorithm
    //Case 1 when slope is < 1
    int X=x1 ,Y=y1;
    int dx = x2-x1 , dy = y2-y1;
    int p;
    int state=1;
    if(dy<dx){
        //Case 1 when slope is < 1
        p = 2*dy - dx;
    }else{
        //Case 1 when slope is > 1
        p = 2*dx - dy;
        state=0;
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    while(X<x2 && state==1){
        glVertex2i(X, Y);
        X++;
        if(p<0){
            p+=(2*dy);
        }else{
            p+=(2*dy-2*dx);
            Y++;
        }
    }

    while(Y<y2 && state==0){
        glVertex2i(X, Y);
        Y++;
        if(p<0){
            p+=(2*dx);
        }else{
            p+=(2*dx-2*dy);
            X++;
        }
    }

    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("My first program");
    myInit();
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The above program runs well when I do not give the user input(for x1,y1,x2,y2) and hardocded them with some random numbers, but on providing the user input it opens a blank window and does not responds.

Suggest what to do?  Is it somethoing related to glut keyboard func?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing standard input/output is not meant to be used with opengl. Why don't you put the values in a file and read them from there.

Comment: Get the input once during initialization instead of continuously in the application loop.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks it worked :) . I just declared my variables globally and took the input from inside the main function. But I was wondering is there any other method to take the input without declaring the varibles globally??

Comment: @RishabPurkayastha No, since `myDisplay` is a callback function, something has to be global. However, you can encapsulate the input in a `struct`.